# Interface or port id to IP address in dpdk 20.11

Tags: dpdk

Are they any existing API's in dpdk (as of 20.11 LTS) to map IP addresses to interfaces (port-id's) or vice versa?

Comment: the answer for your query is updated based on the latest DPDK available. Please accept and/or upvote to close the questio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the current available DPDK `21.05.0` release, there is no direct API that supports the mapping of IP address to port Number. This is because DPDK API does not implement **IP stack**.

if one needs to maintain a simple mapping of IP address to DPDK port, I heavily recommend using a simple array to do so.

```
uin8_t mapPortIp4[RTE_MAX_ETHPORTS][4] = {0};
uint8_t rte_ipv6_hdr mapPortIp6[RTE_MAX_ETHPORTS][16] = {0};

int updateIp4(uin8_t Ip4[4], uint16_t port)
{
  if (port >= rte_eth_dev_count_avail())
    return -1;

  mapPortIp4[port][0] = Ip4[0];
  mapPortIp4[port][1] = Ip4[1];
  mapPortIp4[port][2] = Ip4[2];
  mapPortIp4[port][3] = Ip4[3];

  return 0;
}

int updateIp6(uin8_t Ip6[16], uint16_t port)
{
  if (port >= rte_eth_dev_count_avail())
    return -1;

  mapPortIp6[port][0] = Ip6[0];
  mapPortIp6[port][1] = Ip6[1];
  mapPortIp6[port][2] = Ip6[2];
  mapPortIp6[port][3] = Ip6[3];
  mapPortIp6[port][4] = Ip6[4];
  mapPortIp6[port][5] = Ip6[5];
  mapPortIp6[port][6] = Ip6[6];
  mapPortIp6[port][7] = Ip6[7];
  mapPortIp6[port][8] = Ip6[8];
  mapPortIp6[port][9] = Ip6[9];
  mapPortIp6[port][10] = Ip6[10];
  mapPortIp6[port][11] = Ip6[11];
  mapPortIp6[port][12] = Ip6[12];
  mapPortIp6[port][13] = Ip6[13];
  mapPortIp6[port][14] = Ip6[14];
  mapPortIp6[port][15] = Ip6[15];

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try to create a mapping along the lines of your suggested code. Sidenote: I suspect you meant `updateIp6` for the second function definition instead of `int updateIp4(uin8_t Ip6[16], uint16_t port)`

Comment: @Fractal updated with return value and name change, please check and accept to close the ticket.